# How to use an external variable in linkage section in COBOL and pass values from it into a new module and write into my new output file

Tags: external, cobol, mainframe, jcl, cics

Could someone please tell me why a variable is declared as "External" in a module and how to use that in other modules through Linkage section and how to pass them into new fields so I can write it to a new file.

Answer (score 3):

`EXTERNAL` items are commonly found in `WORKING-STORAGE`. These are normally not passed from one program to another via `CALL` and `LINKAGE` but shared directly via the COBOL runtime.
Declaring an item as `EXTERNAL` behaves like "runtime named global storage", you assign a name and a length to a global piece of memory and can access it anywhere in the same runtime unit (no direct `CALL` needed), even in cases like the following:

```
 MAIN
   -> CALL B
      B: somevar EXTERNAL
      -> MOVE 'TEST' TO somevar
   -> CANCEL B
   -> CALL C
      C: somevar EXTERNAL -> now contains 'TEST'
```

Answer (score 1):

On an IBM Z mainframe, running z/OS, the runtime routines for all High Level Languages (HLLs) is called [Language Environment (LE)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=zos-language-environment).  Decades ago, each HLL had its own runtime and this caused some problems when they were mixed into the same run unit; starting in the early 1990s IBM switched all HLLs to LE for their runtime.

LE has the concept of an [enclave](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=model-enclaves).  Part of the text at that link says an enclave is the equivalent of a run unit in COBOL.

Your question is tagged CICS, and sometimes [behavior is different](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=environment-defining-runtime-options-language) when running in that environment.  Quoting from that link...

> Under CICS the execution of a CICS LINK command creates what Language Environment calls a Child Enclave. A new environment is initialized and the child enclave gets its runtime options. These runtime options are independent of those options that existed in the creating enclave.

[...]

> Something similar happens when a CICS XCTL command is executed. In this case we do not get a child enclave, but the existing enclave is terminated and then reinitialized with the runtime options determined for the new program. The same performance considerations apply.

So, as @SimonSobich noted, if you use CALLs to invoke your subroutines when running in CICS, [EXTERNAL](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.3?topic=entry-external-clause) data is global to the run unit.  But, if you use EXEC CICS XCTL to invoke your subroutines, you may see different behavior and have to design your application differently.